# How can I get atrribute from GraphUser in function includeItem?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I found reference from [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/PickerFragment.GraphObjectFilter#includeItem%28Object%29) and I cannot retrieve all data from `graphObject`. I can

use `graphObject.getName()`, `graphObject.getId()`, `graphObject.getUsername()`.

When I use `graphObject.getInnerJSONObject()`, it just return only picture, id, name.

What should I do if I want more details from this function?